# OK to Add Air Quality Modeling-Related Questions?

Tags: discussion

I started an Air Quality Modeling Community on Area51. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107422/air-quality-modeling
Some folks recommended we join this community instead. Is it OK with you all to funnel our user community here? The questions/answers will be very technical. Is there a way to copy/paste questions from our Area51 to here to seed this community?

Answer (score 3):

I would say most of the questions as currently proposed on Area51 are on-topic.

I'm not too familiar with the scope of air quality modeling.  Certainly, when it's about air pollution, urban air quality, particle dispersion etc., it would be on-topic, as it is intricately related to atmospheric science.  Perhaps even questions more tangential to Earth Science could be welcome, such as questions about *indoor* air quality modelling, but for that one I'm much less sure.  But I don't see any such questions on Area51 so perhaps that would not even be in scope on your proposed site either.

It is true that many questions are rather technical, and there's been some debates before on to what degree technical questions are on-topic.  I think questions on domain-specific software should be on-topic, since an Earth Science audience is more likely to be able to answer WRF questions than a Super User audience.  But if the skill required to answer the question is not domain-specific ("server lists data for air quality modelling X in seperate files, how do I use wget to download them all") then it belongs elsewhere.

I don't think it's possible or desirable to copy/paste questions from the proposal to this site.  Really, the proposal only contains question *titles*.  Most of them would need to be expanded in the body, so copy/paste wouldn't make very good questions.